# This method goes through each frame of an audio clip but keeps returning -1.0 the default value for each value instead of an actual value

Tags: java, audio

According to Oracles website the getLevel() method should return the amplitude of the audio but I have only been getting the default value for floats when the amplitude is not found.

Is there a different way I should do this or is there some other error inside my code I do not know about?

```
public static float[] parseClip(File audio/*Clip audio, AudioInputStream audioInput*/) throws LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {
        Clip clipToBeParsed;
        // Open an audio input stream for the clip to be gone through in separately from the one making noise
        AudioInputStream audioStreamForParsing = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audio);
        // gets the clip
        clipToBeParsed = AudioSystem.getClip();
        // creates a path to a Wav type file, not sure if needed
        clipToBeParsed.open(audioStreamForParsing);
        // gets the total amount of frames in the clip
        int totalFrames = clipToBeParsed.getFrameLength();
        // gets the length of the clip in microseconds
        Long lengthOfClip = clipToBeParsed.getMicrosecondLength();
        // sets the length of each clip for the frames to pause for that long
        Long frameLength = lengthOfClip/(long)totalFrames;
        float amplitude;
        float[] amplitudePositions = new float[totalFrames];
        // cycling through the frames of the clip from beginning to end
        for(int i = 0; i<totalFrames; i++) {
            clipToBeParsed.setFramePosition(i);
            // get level returns the value of the amplitude from 0 to 1.0
            amplitude = clipToBeParsed.getLevel();
            amplitudePositions[i] = amplitude;
        }
        return amplitudePositions;
}
```